# How to debug python tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I already set the `debug=True`then what is the next ? I use eclipse + pydev for develop environment

Give me some details about tornado debugging will be very appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Eclipse, PyDev, PyCharm, or whatever to set a breakpoint at the misbehaving line of code and step through your code from there. Tornado applications are relatively difficult to debug because the stack trace is less clear than in multithreaded code. Step through your code carefully. If you use coroutines, you should become familiar with the implementation of gen.Runner so you can understand what your code does during a "yield".